# Leap-year program in Python

Tags: python

I'm having a very hard time troubleshooting my code. All I'm trying to do is have the user enter in a starting and an ending year, and then be able to calculate all the leap years in between. I'm still very new to Python, and just can't figure out why my while loop isn't doing what I want it to do.

```
starting = int(raw_input('Enter starting year: '))
ending = int(raw_input('Enter ending year: '))
print 'Leap years between', starting, 'and', ending
while starting <= ending:
    if starting % 4 == 0 and starting % 100 != 0:
       print starting
    if starting % 100 == 0 and starting % 400 == 0:
       print starting
    starting = starting + 1
```

That is what I have right now. I really would prefer not to have the answer just given to me, but if I could get a little hint as to why my while loop isn't working I would really appreciate it.

This is the output I see in my IDE:

[image: screenshot of ide]

Comment: So whats the code doing wrong? At a glance this code seems to be working fine.

Comment: Currently it's just completely stopping after printing "Leap years between". Without my while loop that line works just fine, but with my while loop it just stops at that point.

EDIT: I've included a screenshot to show what my code is doing. http://imgur.com/jKa8S3Z,5kxJviX

Comment: Seems to work fine here.

Comment: Very interesting. Try doing `print 'Leap years between {} and {}'.format(starting, ending)`

Comment: Try running it outside of whatever IDE you're using there.

Comment: @Haidro that did solve the print issue, but my while loop still does not run. 

However, it looks like the issue was with my IDE as Games Brainiac seemed to have it work just fine. Really strange and very frustrating considering I've spent hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: You probably did not save your code.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same output as my screenshot still

Comment: Did you tried running your Python code in command line (not in IDE)?

Comment: @user2805735 In your screenshot, you haven't saved the code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is NOT a question

Comment: @user2805735 -- when your question is resolved, please do not edit the question and completely delete everything in it -- it's sort of rude. Leave it untouched so that people who stumble across your question has the full context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is working just fine. This was the following session:

```
Enter starting year: 2008
Enter ending year: 2032
Leap years between 2008 and 2032
2008
2012
2016
2020
2024
2028
2032
```

That corresponds perfectly with the [information give her](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html)e.

Console session:

```
>>> from leapyear import leap
>>> leap()
Enter starting year: >? 2008
Enter ending year: >? 2032
Leap years between 2008 and 2032
2008
2012
2016
2020
2024
2028
2032
```

## leapyear.py

```
def leap():
    starting = int(raw_input('Enter starting year: '))
    ending = int(raw_input('Enter ending year: '))

    print 'Leap years between', starting, 'and', ending
    while starting <= ending:
        if starting % 4 == 0 and starting % 100 != 0:
            print(starting)
        if starting % 100 == 0 and starting % 400 == 0:
            print(starting)
        starting += 1
```

You can also do this function using list comprehensions:

```
def new_leap(start, end):
    return [x for x in xrange(start, end + 1)
            if (x % 400 == 0) or (x % 4 == 0 and not x % 100 == 0)]
```

Console session:

```
>>> from leapyear import new_leap
>>> new_leap(2008, 2032)
[2008, 2012, 2016, 2020, 2024, 2028, 2032]
```

Comment: The logic in the list comprehension is incorrect: for example, it gives 1900 as a leap year.

Comment: @FMc My deepest apologies. I've fixed that now. Would you please take a look?

Answer (score 0):

## I think this will contain all the Test Case

We have added all the invalid cases in value=c
and just matched and removed the value from b

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    leap1=True
    b=[]
    for a in range(1800,year+200,4):
        b.append(a)
    c=[1800,1900,2100,2200,2300,2500,2600,2700,2800,2900]
    for d in range(len(c)):
        e=c[d]
        if e in b:
            b.remove(e)
    if year in b:
        return leap1
    else:
        return leap
year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False

    if year%4 ==0 :
        leap = True

    elif year%100 ==0:
        leap = False

    elif year%400 ==0:
        leap = True

    return leap


year = int(raw_input())
print is_leap(year)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
startingYear = eval(input("Enter starting year:")
endingYear = eval(input("Enter ending year:")

for year in range(startingYear, endingYear + 1):
    if (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0):
        print(year)
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality
Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some
guidelines for How do [I write a good
answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are
**not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted
because they are less useful to a community of learners. Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.